# Class 'System.DBNull' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cn.Open()
        Dim arrimage() As Byte
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        If (pb1.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
            pb1.Image.Save(ms, pb1.Image.RawFormat)
            arrimage = ms.GetBuffer
            ms.Close()
        End If
        With cmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Example]([PName],[Pic])VALUES(@a2,@a1)"
            .Parameters.Add("a0", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tName.Text
            .Parameters.Add("a1", OleDbType.Binary).Value = IIf(pb1.Image IsNot Nothing, arrimage, DBNull.Value())
            .Dispose()
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: There's a few things, firstly you are disposing your command before executing your query. You should execute and then dispose.

Comment: `DBNull.Value()`  value is a property not a method

Comment: Isn't `Using` a more idiomatic choice than `.Close` or `.Dispose`? @Zaggler

Comment: @ZevSpitz of course it is, it ensures objects get disposed. Currently it will never execute the way the OP currently has it, that was my point.

Comment: @Plutonix Any idea what should i do? Im trying to save image in msaccess using vb.net

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark to remove this from the UnAnswered list.  Accepting answers and upvoting helps others find good answers.  The [Tour] explains more.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues in your code.  In order of appearance:

**Dont use GetBuffer()**

As noted on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.MemoryStream.GetBuffer);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true), the buffer can be up to twice the size of the data in the stream.  This will bloat the database needlessly with extra nulls.  Use `ToArray()` instead.

Since images in a DB have to be converted to and from a byte array, consider archiving the images to a folder and store just the name in the database.  You can then prepend the archive folder name to load an image quickly.

Rather than **RawFormat**, I would encode it to something like JPEG.

**Use `Using` blocks**

Anything which has a `.Dispose` method usually needs to be disposed.  This would apply to the `OleDBCommand` object (MemStream really doesnt need to be disposed, but that is an implementaion detail).

`Using` blocks incoporate `Dim`, `New` and `Dispose` in one handy, easy to use block:

```
Using foo As New FooBar()
   ...
End Using
```

The first line declares a `foo` variable, and creates an instance of `FooBar` which you can use inside the block.  At the end, it is disposed of automatically.

**Don't Use Global DBCommand objects**

Your code does not show `cmd` being declared or created, so it must be a form level object.  **Don't Do That**.  There is nothing reusable about a `DBCommand` object unless all your app does is one thing.

In the code you add 2 parameters.  The next time you go to use it, it could still have those 2 and the code will add 2 more which is more than the SQL query requires. In this case, the code disposes of it, but *that* means the next time you go to reference it you will get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

- As noted, your code calls `Dispose` *before* `ExecuteNonQuery` which will crash - you cant use a disposed object.

**`DBNull.Value` is not a method**

As for the compiler error, you have this:

```
IIf(pb1.Image IsNot Nothing, arrimage, DBNull.Value())
```

DBNull.Value is a property, not a method, so the parens are not needed.  Also, you should use the "new" `If` operator rather than the old `IIF` function.  The operator is short-circuited so the part/clause that does not apply is ignored:

```
' should evaluate the data (arrimage) not its source
If(pb1.Image IsNot Nothing, arrimage, DBNull.Value)   ' no parens
```

Revamped code:

```
cn.Open()
Dim arrimage() As Byte = Nothing

If (pb.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        pb.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        arrimage = ms.ToArray()
    End Using
End If

Dim sql = "INSERT INTO [Example]([PName],[Pic]) VALUES (@a2,@a1)"

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("a0", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tName.Text
    If arrimage IsNot Nothing Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("a1", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = arrimage 
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.Add("a1", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = DBNull.Value
    End If
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

cn.Close()
```

- Since the command object is useless without both the query and the connection, I prefer to pass them in the constructor.  It makes the code shorter as well as assures that it has what it needs
- Connections also ought to be created, used and disposed of each time
- It is also easy to create a handy extension method for converting an image to a byte array